# Unregulated Push pull converter simulation (LTspice) and flux walking

Tags: dc-dc-converter, push-pull, magnetic-flux

I am simulating a unregulated push pull converter in LTspice (voltage isolator). There is the effect of growing winding currents during the simulation. Is this a flux walk (seen in the first image) ?

[image]

I have the duty cycle shown here (~90%)

[image]

And this circuit. (The low input/output capacitances are intentional). Is there a significant error somewhere i am missing, what can i do to fix this ? Explanation of the source of this would be helpful

[image]

Comment: Run the simulation for more than 2ms to see if things stabilize. I think you are seeing the transient response here (initial conditions ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got one MOSFET driven at about 60% and the other MOSFET driven about 40% duty cycle - that puts dc into your transformer and walks the flux.

If anyone reads this focusses on the 2nd picture you'll hopefully see what I mean. I've had to invert the colours and make yellow red to make it viewable more legibly: -

[image]

If you are driving a centre-tapped transformer like this you have to keep the average on-time for both transistors the same. Now this sounds like a "ban" on PWM control but it isn't; one way you can PWM the transformer is just reduce the on time for both transistor whilst keeping as short a gap between the two pulses as possible. So you charge current in one direction proportional to on-time, then discharge current (via the other transistor) for an equal length of time, then hold-off for some period until ready to start the re-charge process. This keeps the magnetization current from walking the core into saturation.

Comment: I've been curious about this and I like the answer. But I have a question, too. Because of part variations, drive variations, etc., it seems that there may still be slight, residual differences in the exact timing even if driving things as you say. Is it the case that the gap between operation of the transistors is how this slight difference is "made up for" in the end? That there must be enough of a gap to cover over this slight issue and allow an exact zero for the accumulation of volt-seconds? I keep thinking one must _observe_ that the current reaches zero.

Comment: @jonk after the 2nd transistor turns off any residual current (aka energy) will dissipate in the snubber.. Even if going full pelt the small off time between successive transistor switching will remove a lot of that energy but it can be a problem without care to the detail.

Comment: Thanks. I felt that care would be required and you've confirmed it. This is a very tricky area (to me, when I've thought about it) and I've refrained from going this direction in part because I could handle my problems other ways and in part because I was worried about just how much learning curve ahead I might have in getting this done well and correctly.

Comment: To make things worse there's not much on the internet about driving transformers like this with pwm. What I have found doesn't appear to go into much detail about timing. I've chickened out in the past and put a really efficient buck regulator feeding the centretap with feedback control of it with the push pull transistors going full pelt with accurate 50-50 timing.

Comment: Well, you've confirmed by "fears" and as a hobbyist I'll probably stay clear of this. It's not as though I these are goals of mine, anyway. Just means to ends. I'll use techniques I know how to do and continue holding short of this one. I like the centertap idea. Thanks for the thoughts. You've settled this issue just a little further for me.

Comment: Hobbyist? You have a good working knowledge of pyrometry which is amazing if you are just a hobbyist or am I mixing you up with someone else LOL

Comment: Yeah. I'm a hobbyist. Never taken a single class on electronics, not even a DC class. All book-learned + experience. Pyrometry and phosphor thermometry and human color perception are areas where I've actually worked to develop instrumentation on a professional basis. I built three telescopes (grinding glass for thousands of hours and then doing a variety of tests) by the time I was 20, two of which I'd designed. So optics is an area I kind of know a little about. I also worked on the first writable CD project (polymers, etc.) Zero electronics though.

Comment: Yay. I can smell a good engineer from a mile way @jonk and you are one of them. What you learn formally in class only ever gives self belief, what you learn by practise gives you much more.

Comment: I've learned a lot from folks like you along the way, who've given their time and thoughts to help me acquire their mental models. So thanks for the kind comment, but really most of all thanks for the time you've given (and to others like you.)

Comment: Andy was right with the duty cycle. Good answer and many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**My solution was to check the "Start external voltages at zero" checkbox.** I just have a simple push-pull circuit simulated, and the gate waveforms were perfectly symmetrical... to the nanosecond. Damn thing pulled 6kA at the very first pulse *rolls eyes*. Indeed, it's flux walking, leading to core saturation. In real life, there are circuits to keep the net DC current through each winding the same. Yes, it's a little tricky. Yes, it's necessary...